# How to handle return value of SnowflakeOperator in Airflow

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm currently experimenting with Airflow for monitoring tasks regarding Snowflake and I'd like to execute a simple DAG with one task that pushes a SQL query to in Snowflake and should check the returned value that should be a number to be greater than a defined threshold.

So the following is basically my sql Statement in the DAG definition:

```
query_check = """select COUNT(*)
FROM (select CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%SW_PRODUCTFEED%' THEN 'PRODUCTFEED'
        ELSE NULL END AS TASKTREE_NAME
       , NAME 
       , STATE
       , ERROR_MESSAGE
       , SCHEDULED_TIME
       , QUERY_START_TIME
       , NEXT_SCHEDULED_TIME
  from table(TEST_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.task_history())
  where TASKTREE_NAME IS NOT NULL
  qualify DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TASKTREE_NAME ORDER BY to_date(SCHEDULED_TIME) desc) < 3
  order by scheduled_time desc);"""
```

Then the following is the definition of the DAG and the task within it:

```
with dag:
    query1_exec = SnowflakeCheckOperator(
        task_id="snowflake_check_task_history",
        sql=query_check,
        params={
            "check_name": "number_rows",
            "check_statement": "count >=1"
        },
        conn_id="Snowflake_test"
    )

query1_exec
```

I'd like to use the `SnowflakeCheckOperator` to check the returned value from the query if it's greater than 1

However, it seems that Snowflake or the SnowflakeOperator in that case is returning the result of the query in a dict object, like so:

```
Record: {'COUNT(*)': 10}
```

Therefore the check always results in a true statement because the SnowflakeCheckOperator isn't checking against the value of the Record["Count"] but something else.

Now my question is how to handle the return value so that the check is evaluated against right value? Is it possible to change the format of the return value? Or maybe get access to the value of the key of the dict object?

Answer (score 1):

In apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==4.0.2 there was a [breaking change](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/index.html#breaking-changes), which fixed the issue you are having.

> The SnowflakeHook is now conforming to the same semantics as all the
> other DBApiHook implementations and returns the same kind of response
> in its run method. Previously (pre 4.* versions of the provider, the
> Hook returned Dictionary of { "column": "value" ... } which was not
> compatible with other DBApiHooks that return just sequence of
> sequences. After this change (and dependency on common.sql >=
> 1.3.1),the SnowflakeHook returns now python DbApi-compatible “results” by default.